# Angular 4 .subscribe not updating UI

Tags: angular, typescript

Here is the typescript function I wrote:

```
public fetchSubject() {
 this.loading.joinBtn = true;
 this.apiService.get('classroom_details?class_code=' + this.code)
 .subscribe((res) => {
  console.log('API request successful');
  this.loading.joinBtn = false;
  this.modalDiv = 'class';
  console.log('Button state is: ', this.loading.joinBtn, '. Display: ', this.modalDiv);
  }, error => {
  console.log('API Request Failed');
  this.loading.joinBtn = false;
  });
}
```

The function seems to work perfectly as I get the desired values in console.log. However, it's not updating the UI. Neither of the two changes i.e. `this.loading.joinBtn` and `this.modalDiv` reflect on the UI.

When I move the modalDiv change line outside apiService, something like:

```
public fetchSubject() {
this.loading.joinBtn = true;
this.modalDiv = 'class';
this.apiService.get('classroom_details?class_code=' + this.code).......
```

The UI is updated. However, I would like to update the UI only after API request is completed. What seems to be the problem here?

Comment: can you share html template, how you bind class to `modalDiv`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Angular is not able to detect changes.

To handle such kind of issue, please create instance of `ChangeDetectorRef` in your class constructor like mentioned below:

```
constructor(private cd: ChangeDetectorRef) {};
```

And after assigning values to object please call changeDetection explicitly inside subscription as mentioned below:

```
this.loading.joinBtn = false;
this.modalDiv = 'class';
this.cd.detectChanges()
```